# How To set default UTF-8 in Http Test Script Recorder In Jmeter?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter and I record http requsets with "Http Test Script Recorder".

How can I set default UTF-8 encoding for the content encoding?

When I record, for the first time, encoding has been a problem, but content encoding for the next time, is ok.

Comment: what do you mean by first time and second time? can you please provide some images of the flow?

Comment: first time and second time not important.when i record with script recorder, UTF-8 is not set to default in content encoding and the name of my operation will be like this : ???? ???? ????

Answer (score 0):

Add a `HTTP REQUEST DEFAULT` to the test plan and set Content encoding to `UTF-8` Then start recording the website

If it didn't help (That's because the website you are recording is sending a request which is not UTF-8 encoded, If you can change the source code of website do it first, else try these steps), You can use USER DEFINED VARIABLES in the test plan:

- Click Add
- In Name define a variable name i.e: sur_name
- Then in value write the name you want i.e: صادقی
- In any HttpRequest with parameter named sur_name you should write @sur_name as value

Note that you should do the steps after monitoring.

Comment: I've done this before, but the problem has not been resolved.
This item does not work when recording.

Comment: Plz paste the link of uploaded jmx here

Comment: thank you 
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=83056455078909962720 Jmeter File 
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=88176191138427545184 Help

Comment: thank you very much. my website is utf-8 default and i don't have permission to change encoding. i think, my certificate or proxy for recording is not properly working. User defined variables is only for static plan and my plans is dynamic and while recording http, define variable is not Practical.

Comment: in addition to this, if my site was not utf-8. The second record was not sent in UTF-8 encoding !!! I think this is a bug from the Jmeter.

Comment: @MiladSadeghi if you want join this room to talk about the problem live : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/192549/jmeter?tab=general

Comment: sure, but after 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk with you